# Presence Indicator not Active in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, presence-indication

I have SharePoint 2016 enterprise with Office 2016 and Skype 2016 (but we also have Exchange 2010).  Is there a setting in Skype 2016 that is required for SharePoint 2016 to pick up the users status in the Presence Indicator or is this tied to Exchange?

Bismarck

Comment: What browser you using IE or chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: The Desktop team installed Skype for Business Basic as a separate install and then installed Office 2016 Pro and unchecked Skype for Business.  Resolving it was to remove the stand-alone Skype for Business and re-install it through the Office 2016 Pro (Add/Remove Programs).

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

Check from central admin if “Person Name Actions and Presence Settings” enabled for the web application, you can check by `Go to Central Admin -> Manage Web Applications -> Select your web app -> General Settings`

Also Check this one:

**Issue:**

You have Lync running and open a SharePoint web page with IE (internet explorer) and the user presence information does not show.

**Workaround:**

Find the IE security zone the SharePoint site is in, and turn off "protected mode" for the IE security zone.

Or run IE as administrator

**Issue Details:**

The Office IE add-on loops though all the processes on the computer looking for Lync, so it can use a handle to the process to communicate with it.  When IE is enforcing protected mode Windows security restricts the process list that is sent back to the Office IE add-on and the Lync handle is inaccessible.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2015/04/16/lync-presence-information-does-not-show-in-sharepoint-web-page/